# Is there a way to practice moves against a friend without the match ending?

Tags: marvel-vs-capcom-3

Is there a way in Marvel vs. Capcom 3 to either:

1. play in training mode with two human players?
2. play in versus mode with unlimited health?

I'd really love to be able to just practice moves with a friend without having to end the match.

Comment: Couldn't you just set the opponent to be player controlled?

Comment: Can you?  I'm not sure how to do that.  I'm on XBox 360

Comment: When in training mode, there's usually an option to set how the opponent behaves.  Look in the pause menu.

Comment: I believe Jeff is right, and you can just set the AI to player controlled.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the Options menu, under Dummy Options, choose "Player" as the Action.

Comment: Ok good, I didn't know the exact names there.